# Why isn't my map being updated?

Tags: clojure

Pretty new to clojure so be kind.

```
(def state {:currentPosition "1"})

(while (not= (state :currentPosition) "2") ; this is true
  (assoc state :currentPosition "2") ; 
)
```

This causes an infinite loop and it wont run but I don't understand why. The condition

```
 (not= (state :currentPosition) "2")
```

is true

therefore, the loop starts, then inside the loop, I am updating the state. Why doesn't the loop end and just stalls light table? Thanks

Comment: Ben, Piotr's answer is correct given what you specifically asked.  You may know this, but the kind of thing you're doing is not idiomatic.  (Sometimes you need to do this kind of thing anyway, which is why atoms exist.)  It's fine to do things the way you're used to doing them when you very first learn the language, but you'll want to learn Clojure-style coding strategies pretty quickly.  It can be kind of awkward at first, but once you get used to functional programming, it's beautiful and fun (imho).  If I'm telling you things you already have heard, just ignore this comment.

Comment: I totally agree, i'm trying to program 'normally'. It's just a real big change to what i'm used to lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Clojure datastructures](https://clojure.org/reference/data_structures) are immutable so `(assoc state :currentPosition "2")` doesn't mutate the object assigned to `state` var but just returns a new version of a map.

If you want to modify values in your vars you need to wrap them in one of [Clojure's refs](http://clojure.org/reference/refs). You could for example use `atom`:

```
(def state (atom {:currentPosition 1}))

(reset! state {:currentPosition 2})    
@state ;; => {:currentPosition 2}

(swap! state update :currentPosition inc)
@state ;; => {:currentPosition 3}
```

Comment: hey I can't test if it works because when I try to do:  (not= (state :currentPosition) "2")    it says Atom cannot be cast to IFn  Any ideas? thank you again

Comment: When you want to read a value from an atom you need to `deref` it: `(deref currentPosition)`. There is also a shorthand version: `@currentPosition`

Comment: Great! I see what you mean about the deref but I think I had to deref the object, not the currentPosition like so: (not= ((deref state) :currentPosition) "2")   how do you mean with the @currentPosition

Comment: nevermind, just got it!  (not=  (@state :currentPosition) "2")  thanks very much

Comment: Hey, it' sstill not working in the loop :(   here is code if you'd like a look https://codeshare.io/3lAfX

Comment: In one place you have `2` and in the other `"2"`